# Reviews are offered even while I'm banned!

Tags: support, review

Due to my sloppiness in reviewing, I've been blocked from reviewing for a while. However, on my home page, I'm shown a non-zero number of items to review. Why?

Answer (score 5):

Because the number of items doesn't depend on the user seeing it. It's the same for everyone. It doesn't change if you've done all the reviewing you can do in a day, and it doesn't change if you've voted for everything in the queues so can't review anything else and it doesn't change if you're blocked from reviewing.

This is explained in the main meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/203101):

> It is also cached, so may or may not be very accurate depending on the amount of ongoing activity in /review at any given time.

Basically, the number shown isn't the number of reviews *you* can do, but the number of review items for the entire site.

Comment: The last paragraph is true only for 10k+ users. Below 10k you see the number of edit reviews, if I remember it right.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yup, us common folks only see the number of suggested edits.

Comment: @Pilot6 I think you see the number of review items in all queues you have access to. Not sure though.

Comment: I believe the linked answer is not valid for <10k users. I believe the number is customized for us, and only shows the number of suggested edits we can review. From what I observe, when I review an edit the number will decrease even if the review is not completed, and the post I'm reviewing is still in the queue (for example, if I select "skip"). *Need to refresh the page though, since the queue uses [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))*

Comment: @Dan huh, however, that might just be because the number of edit review items is very low and only take 2 confirmations to approve. So, if your reviewing it knocks it out of the queue, you'll see the number change. In any case, none of this is really relevant to the question here. The main point is that the number you see doesn't depend on your own status.